# How secure it is to use Client Side recaptcha?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using Angular recaptcha here: https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha

It is implemented successfully client side and on server side I am doing it like below to validate if user confirmed the captcha or not.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'EmailAddress' =>  'required',
        'Password'     =>  'required',
        'Captcha'      =>  'required',
    ];
}
```

I have a couple of question about the security

> 1. I think I can use anybody's public key to implement this because I am not making server side validation. Should I implement recaptcha
>      server and client side both?
> 2. I can send any string from client side(AngularJs) to validate so anybody can inject any string to get rid of automated calls. This is
>      because the server side rule has only required key.

Is there any way to make it secure?

Comment: Your final check/validation has to be always on the server side. The client side code can be seen and manipulated by anyone, so client side code is just for user feedback, but not for validating the data that is send to your server.

Comment: Do you have any link to cross check validate the response from client side in server side? I meant do I need any api to send response received from client side?

Comment: I neither use angular nor laravel so I can give you a specific link. When the client sends the data to your server you have to validate it there, if validation fails then send a respones with the info why it failed back to the client otherwise process the data and send a success response to the client.

Comment: My questions is: how should I validate the client response in server side? I meant, Do I need another api call to validate the client response?

Answer (score 0):

Here is official code example from google. It's written in php. You can check how they handle server side validation. Follow link [on GitHub](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/)